# Use foreach to access second array dimension as a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [10060] => Array
        (
            [127] => Array
                (
                )

            [130] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [10070] => Array
        (
            [127] => Array
                (
                )

            [130] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

I want to access the second dimension's key using a foreach like this:

```
foreach(array_keys($adamBrownsArray[100060][]) as $secondDimension)
{
  echo($secondDimension);
}
```

**How can I reference the second dimension when I just want to list all the keys and use them as a variable?** (note I left the second dimensions brackets empty above)

Expected echoed output would be:

```
127
130
```

Comment: there are commands to see all the key inside an array

Answer (score 2):

You simply want keys of second level arrays.

So, loop over the main array, you will get the second level arrays.

Get the keys of that using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
<?php
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r(array_keys($elem));
  echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: But if I know the key of the first dimension how can I include this?

Comment: If you want to know the keys of the first dimension, use array_keys() for $arr that is main array.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `[]` in your code and that prevents it working. Try this:

```
foreach(array_keys($adamBrownsArray[100060]) as $secondDimension)
{
    echo($secondDimension);
}
```

Take a look at the list of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) in the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$keys = array_keys(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $your_array));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($keys);
```